# Apache TLS Handshakes Timeout after DHCP Lease Renewal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to figure out why my HTTPS sites go down everytime my server's DHCP lease gets renewed.

It happens consistently, but HTTP sites continue to work just fine.

Restarting systemd-networkd brings the sites back, but until that happens the HTTPS sites are basically unreachable.

Any tips on where to look first?

The weird thing is these sites come back after the next DHCP lease renewal, then I lose connectivity on the next one, then it comes back, then I lose it, on and on.

This is what I see in syslog when it happens.

```
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd-networkd[13973]: ens4: DHCP lease lost
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd-networkd[13973]: ens4: DHCPv4 address 10.138.0.29/32 via 10.138.0.1
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd-networkd[13973]: ens4: IPv6 successfully enabled
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 dbus-daemon[579]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.231' (uid=101 pid=13973 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd " label="unconfined")
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd-networkd[13973]: ens4: Configured
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 dbus-daemon[579]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr 13 18:06:25 www-1 systemd-hostnamed[17589]: Changed host name to 'www-1.us-west1-b.c.camp-fire-259800.internal'
```

Comment: Did you make any changes within the instance? If so, please share those changes.

Comment: I just started over with a new VM, new IPs and everything. 
Ran apt update/upgrade & added a few SSH keys, a disk + edits to fstab.
I also added a few internal hosts to /etc/hosts.

Problem persists.

Comment: Does the dhcp client interact with the firewall at all? It's odd that DHCP lease renewals are basically toggling 443.

Comment: I think I figured it out... mostly. 
It was related to DNS. Basically 127.0.0.53 was failing after dhcpclient renewed my lease, so switching the /etc/resolv.conf symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf solved that issue. However, now /etc/hosts is basically ignored. Any ideas how to get that working?

Comment: Here are some links I found when trying to track down the specific issue.
https://moss.sh/name-resolution-issue-systemd-resolved/
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9243

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to the following:
https://moss.sh/name-resolution-issue-systemd-resolved/
and
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9243

I've disabled systemd-resolved and am using a static /etc/resolv.conf copied from /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

For internal DNS I'm using a private Google DNS Zone.

Thanks.